# Custom Scala Form Template

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to define my own custom template so that when I type:

```
@inputText(
  myForm("firstName"),
  '_label -> "First Name"
)
```

​
It would spit out the following html

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-lg-12" for="firstname">First Name</label>
 <div class="col-sm-9">
   <input id="firstName" class="form-control" type="text" name="firstName">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am drinking lavender tea with biscuits ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom fieldConstructorTemplate.

1. Create a file named `<urname>.scala.html`
2. Then in there write the following code:

   ```
   @(elements: helper.FieldElements)
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-lg-12" for="@elements.id">@elements.label</label>
     <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="@elements.field.name"
       value="@elements.field.value"></input>
    </div>
   ```
3. Next in your scala template where you use the:

   ```
   @inputText( myForm("firstName"), '_label -> "First Name")

   @implicitField = @{ FieldConstructor(yourFieldConstructorTemplateName.f) }
   ```